# Read in R a file with different line lengths into a List

Tags: r, file, file-io

I would like to read a file into a list of arrays with each line representing a list element.  Each line has a different number of elements and different  The first value in the line would be the list key and the remaining data would be the members of the array.

e.g. file example

```
1 100,50,2,5,78
2 5,4,2,1
3 1
4 7,2,9,0,23,5,6,7,8,2,3,4
5 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
6 1,8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work well

```
dd<-scan("example.txt", list("character", "character"))
Map(function(a,b)b, dd[[1]], strsplit(dd[[2]],","))
```

Here use use `scan` to read the first column as one vector and the second as another. Then we strsplit the second on commas and use one of the side-effects of Map to pull the names from the first column and use them as labels of the vectors from the second column. If you wanted the vector values to be numeric you could do

```
Map(function(a,b) as.numeric(b), dd[[1]], strsplit(dd[[2]],","))

# $`1`
# [1] 100  50   2   5  78
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 5 4 2 1
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 1
# 
# $`4`
#  [1]  7  2  9  0 23  5  6  7  8  2  3  4
# 
# $`5`
#  [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
# 
# $`6`
# [1] 1 8
```